# How to permit Doctrine in the ZF2 repeat accepted data

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

How do I allow the Doctrine accepted data to be repeated in ZF2? Following error appears:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'contrato' 
                 for key 'menu'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove unique index from this field

Comment: Thank Kosov, I also found this http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html